# Oracle left outer join issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having an issue in a reporting SQL with left outer join.

```
 SELECT * FROM xx.aa 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN xx.yyy
           ON aa.some_column_1 = yyy.some_column_1
           AND aa.some_column_2 = yyy.some_column_2
           AND aa.some_column_3 = yyy.some_column_3
           AND yyy.some_year = '2015'
           AND yyy.some_column_4 IS NOT NULL
           AND yyy.some_column_4 > 0
 WHERE aa.some_column_1 = '1234' 
   AND aa.some_column_2 = 'SOME_VALUE'
   AND aa.end_date >= TO_DATE('01-JAN-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
   AND aa.start_date <= TO_DATE('31-DEC-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
   AND (aa.some_column_3 = 'SOME_VALUE')
```

Table aa

```
some_column_1 some_column_2 some_column_3 start_date end_date
1234          SOME_VALUE    SOME_VALUE    1/1/2011   6/30/2014
1234          SOME_VALUE    SOME_VALUE    7/1/2014   6/30/2015
```

Table yyy

```
some_column_1 some_column_2 some_column_3 some_column_4 some_year
1234          SOME_VALUE    SOME_VALUE    444           2015
```

However, the last two conditions in the left outer join, `IS NOT NULL` and  `> 0`, should ONLY be applied when there is MORE THAN 1 ROW MATCHED and if AT LEAST one of the rows satisfies both conditions. Else it will be a problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you need a subquery and `CASE`. You should post entire SQL statement because we don't see anything of `aa` and `location`. You can make it `a.f1, b.f1. c.f3`, etc. We don't need long names

Comment: Please see updated thank you!

Comment: @user3224907 Where is the sample data in your update?

Comment: Added sample data @FutbolFan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the query without the condition in the left join, then do a discution about your conditions to decide the values from yyy table if they are null or not.

```
select aa_col1, aa_col2, ..., aa_coln,
    case when cnt > 2 and cond > 1 
              and not (yyy_some_column_4 IS NOT NULL AND yyy_some_column_4 > 0) 
         then null else yyy_col1 
         end as yyy_col1,
    ,...the other columns of yyy
from(
    SELECT aa.*, yyy.*,
      count(*) over() as cnt,
      count(case when yyy.some_column_4 IS NOT NULL AND yyy.some_column_4 > 0  then 1 end) over() as cond
    FROM xx.aa 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN xx.yyy
        ON aa.some_column_1 = yyy.some_column_1
               AND aa.some_column_2 = yyy.some_column_2
               AND aa.some_column_3 = yyy.some_column_3
               AND yyy.some_year = '2015'
     WHERE aa.some_column_1 = '1234' 
       AND aa.some_column_2 = 'SOME_VALUE'
       AND aa.end_date >= TO_DATE('01-JAN-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
       AND aa.start_date <= TO_DATE('31-DEC-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
       AND (aa.some_column_3 = 'SOME_VALUE')
)
```

At line 8 you should alias the columns so they be distinct in the upper select. I named them aa_col1, yyy_col1, etc.

Comment: Slight problem, i'm not able to select from aa. When I select aa_col1, aa_col2, ... or any column from aa, it is saying column ambiguously defined. If I provide aa.aa_col1, it says invalid identifier.

Comment: Work when I explicitly spell out the column names instead of doing `SELECT aa.*, yyy.*,`. Thanks for your help. I have a problem from the same report, if you happen to have a chance please look at it: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084141/oracle-issue-with-reporting-sql?noredirect=1#comment52066153_32084141)