# Oracle issue with reporting SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a reporting SQL in Oracle which is using the `SUM` function.

Table Y

```
CLIENT_NUM  LOCATION_CODE EFFECTIVE_DATE EXPIRY_DATE
1234        AB01          1/1/2011       6/30/2014
1234        AB01          7/1/2014       8/31/2014
1234        AB01          9/1/2014       6/30/2015
1234        AB66          1/1/2011       6/30/2014
1234        AB66          7/1/2014       8/31/2014
1234        AB66          9/1/2014       6/30/2015
```

Table X

```
CLIENT_NUM LOCATION_CODE EMPLOYEE_COUNT TOTAL_HOURS_WORKED REPORTING_YEAR
1234       AB01          600            12000              2014
1234       AB66          50             11000              2014
```

SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(x.EMPLOYEE_COUNT) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY CASE ':input_parm:'
                         WHEN 'LOCATION' THEN y.LOCATION_CODE || ' ' || y.LOCATION_NAME
                         WHEN 'CLIENT' THEN y.CLIENT_NUM|| ' ' ||z.CLIENT_NAME 
                         END
               ) AS EMPLOYEE_COUNT 
     , SUM(x.TOTAL_HOURS_WORKED) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY CASE ':input_parm:'
                             WHEN 'LOCATION' THEN y.LOCATION_CODE || ' ' || y.LOCATION_NAME
                             WHEN 'CLIENT' THEN y.CLIENT_NUM|| ' ' ||z.CLIENT_NAME 
                             END
           ) AS TOTAL_HOURS_WORKED 
FROM Y
LEFT OUTER JOIN X
    ON Y.CLIENT_NUM = X.CLIENT_NUM
   AND Y.LOCATION_CODE = X.LOCATION_CODE
   AND X.REPORTING_YEAR = '2014'
   AND location.EFFECTIVE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-:in_reporting_year:','DD-MON-YYYY')
                                   AND TO_DATE('31-DEC-:in_reporting_year:','DD-MON-YYYY')
WHERE Y.CLIENT_NUM='1234' 
AND (Y.LOCATION_CODE='AB66' OR Y.LOCATION_CODE='AB01')
```

This is doubling the numbers up and returning the following when passing "`CLIENT`" or "`LOCATION`" for `:input_parm:` and `2014` for `:in_reporting_year:`

```
EMPLOYEE_COUNT TOTAL_HOURS_WORKED
1300           46000
1300           46000
```

This is the expected output:

```
EMPLOYEE_COUNT TOTAL_HOURS_WORKED
650            23000
650            23000
```

How can I further filter the join to match only one?

Comment: Perhaps `LOCATION` shouldn't always be in single quotes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I didn't understand?

Comment: No, it is passed in from outside. It actually looks like `':input_parm:'` in dynamic sql.

Comment: can you try using `location_code in ('NB66','NB01')` instead of `or` in the `where` clause?

Comment: That actually looks like `AND (:location_cd:)` in dynamic sql.

Comment: But either way, it still does not work with that.

Comment: what are the results you get without `sum() over()`?

Comment: The correct numbers, as expected

Comment: will `inner join` not work for you?

Comment: Nope, I've tried that

Comment: Something looks odd here - there's no `FROM`, so I don't see how this could even execute. Also, table `Y` doesn't seem to be defined here - perhaps because of the missing `FROM`. ???

Comment: Whoops, must have accidentally removed it while doing an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two rows in `Y` for the same `location_code` and `client_num` pairs that you're joining on. So the join is duplicating your results and thus the doubling in the totals.

I'm guessing you'll need to match on one of the dates values somehow.

EDIT: To address your question in comments you could try changing `FROM Y` to the following:

```
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_NUM, LOCATION_CODE FROM Y) as Y
```

Comment: How about doing the aggregation first and then joining? So numbers don't double when joined.. is that a possibility? How could I do that though? The method you suggest may not work because of the whole reporting SQL. This is just a portion.

Comment: I think that aggregating first would certainly work. I'm not really sure what the data in table Y represents and why you need that join.

Comment: Could you show me a way I could do it with your suggested method by using the dates assuming we may have dates for the same location_code in the same year?